# How to set long text into Excel cell from html table

Tags: javascript, html, excel, reactjs, html-table

I'm using script to save a html table to an Excel file, but when i put long text into cell it has too little width.
I didn't find clear description how does this script work, is it possible to specify width for creating cells in excel file?

```
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; })
    }
    , downloadURI = function (uri, name) {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = name;
      link.href = uri;
      link.click();
    }

  return function (table, name, fileName) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    var resuri = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    downloadURI(resuri, fileName);
  }
})()
```

[Created Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClQJI.jpg)